# IIS 301 redirect non-www to www for multple sites pointed at same physical path. Regex

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, pattern-matching, multiple-domains

I have multiple sites setup in IIS which point to the same physical structure on the hard drive i.e. there is only one web config file for all sites.

I need to redirect all non-www traffic for all sites to with www.

For example, this condition in the IIS url rewrite would work for a single domain, but it doesn't work for me because the domain name has to be specified:

```
Input: {HTTP_HOST}
Type: Matches the Pattern
Pattern: ^domain.com\$

Redirect URL: http://www.domain.com/{R:1}
Redirect Type: Permanent 301
```

So ideally I need two regex patterns, one for the pattern to match all domains (these are a mixture of .co.uk, .com, .uk.com etc), and one to redirect to for the redirect URL.

It also needs to work for https://

Can anyone help, all advice is much appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match it directly with a regex, because the regex is applied only to the path, which doesn't include the host (domain name): [Accessing URL Parts from a Rewrite Rule](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule).

If you need to include a condition on the host name, you need to add a `<condition>` to your rule:

> The <host> is available in the server variable HTTP_HOST and can be accessed by using a condition within a rule.

The conditions are defined as explained here [as explained here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rule_conditions).

Finally, you can refer back to the conditions in a similar way to how you refer back to the regex matches in the path, but using the syntax `{C:1}` instead or `{R:1}`.

For a final clue on how to do it, [see this](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules). Basically you have to do adapt this rulte to your particular case:

```
<rule name="Rewrite subdomain">
   <match url="^(.+)" > 
   <!-- rule back-reference is captured here -->
   <conditions>
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" type="Pattern"
          pattern="^([^.]+)\.mysite\.com$">
     <!-- condition back-reference is captured here -->
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:1}" />
   <!-- rewrite action uses back-references to condition and 
        to rule when rewriting the url -->
</rule>
```

Yo only need to do two simple changes:

- modify the condition pattern to capture only non-www host names. This regex: `(^(?!www\.).*$)` will capture all host names that doesn't start with `"www."`
- rewrite the url including the missing `www.` In this case, use this: `url="www.{C:1}/{R:1}"`

*NOTE: this rule does a rewrite. You can do a redirect instead, of allow other rule after this one to do the redirect*

*NOTE 2: you'll need to create two different rules to handle http and https, in a similar fashion. They're on the `{HTTPS}` server variable, which can be `"on"` or `"off"`. In each rule you should include the action `url="http://www.{C:1}/{R:1}"` or `url="https://www.{C:1}/{R:1}"`*

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints. So does {C:1} refer back to the {HTTP_HOST} part of the condition? Sorry I'm useless with regex so I'm none the wiser with modifying the condition pattern

Comment: I did think that my pattern needed to be ^(.*)$ but I'm not sure

Comment: I found this post but it doesn't work for me: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/redirecting-non-www-to-domain-equivalent

Comment: Please, see the updated answer. And remember that this rule is a rewrite, so it should be before any other rule, or covnerted to a redirect rule

Comment: Thank you again. It doesn't seem to work though. I just get a blank page and no addition of www. I noticed you labelled your rule as "rewrite subdomain", however I am working with the top level domain(s).

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/redirecting-non-www-to-domain-equivalent - this example gives me what I need for the non-www, however if I go to www.example.com the rule redirects me www.www.example.com and I can't seem to fix that.

Comment: If you are using the expression in the sample, it matches only host that has two parts separated by a dot. If you use the regex that I've provided you, it will only match hosts that doesn't start with `www.`. So both expressions should work.Please post you config for further investigation

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your time helping me.   Here is my config                `<rule name="non-www to www http" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>`

Comment: I have also tried with your suggestions - PS I am trying to do a redirect rule  -   `<rule name="non-www to www http" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(^(?!www\.).*$)" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="www.{C:1}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>`

Comment: Is that the only rule in your UrlRewite config? If not, leave only this rule, and test it, and tell me if it still fails. It shouldn't

Comment: It seems to be working now, but only for .com domains. Any idea how to change the regular expression to get it working for .co.uk etc? I tried to change the regular expression to `^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)`  but this sends www. to www.www. - the same issue I was having before. Also, if I add `<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />` to my condition, I get redirected to http://www.off ?!?! I have no idea whats happening there :-(

Comment: As I explained, the regex in the sample page only checks that the host name has two parts separated by a dot. My regex checks that the domain name doesn't start with `www.` Draw your own conclusions ;)

Comment: BTW, you can test the expressions for URL and contidions in IIS Manager. If you open the URL Rewrite configuration and edit the rules, you'll find a textbox wher you can type your expression, and test it against the expression. It will also show you the content of {R:0}, {R:1}, etc. or {C:0},{C:1}, etc. I suppose it must read "Pattern", and "Test Pattern". I've got a localized IIS Manager.